# How can I share same action with two names on ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

The situation is, I need to use the same method for two action names in a ASP.NET controller. To elaborate, say `http://mydomain/Members/Index` and `http://mydomain/Members/Browse` should act as same or, have the same method as below for only Members controller:

```
public ActionResult Browse()
{
    var members = _dbContext.Members.ToList();

    return View("Browse", members);
}
```

Currently, I am using two ActionResults named "Browse" and "Index" with the same code but may be there is a better way to do this. I looked into Attributes but **ActionName** Attribute doesn't help me with what I need. Also, google searches give me suggestions with **same methods but different HTTP request types** and **method overloading** examples. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: why you cant just create a private method in controller and call it inside 2 actions?

Comment: Create a specific route for `Index` that points to `Browse` - `url: "Members/Index", defaults: new { controller = "Members", action = "Browse" }`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. I've used your way.

Comment: @maxs87 Thanks for your suggestion mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Index action in the controller and added a exclusive route for **"Members/Browse"** to point to the **"Index"** action of **"Members"** Controller. because in the other way around, **"Members/"** gives 404 error.

Here is the controller action now (example):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var members = _dbContext.Members.ToList();

    return View("Index", members);
}
```

Routes defined in RouteConfig now:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MemberBrowseRoute",
    url: "Members/Browse",
    defaults: new { Controller = "Members", Action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```